# wpf checkbox in listview binding two way

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, listview, data-binding

I have a WPF application which uses Entity Framework to communicate with Database. I have 4 fields in database. My intention is whenever a user selects any particular column with the checkbox which is present inside a listview, I need to update the database IsChecked property on button click. but its not updating the backend..Please help

```
public partial class Datagrid
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsChecked { get; set; }
    }

public partial class SampleDbContext : DbContext
{
 public virtual DbSet<Datagrid> Datagrids { get; set; }
}
```

CS CODE:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Datagrid> data { get; set; }
        public List<Datagrid> lst = new List<Datagrid>();
        private SampleDbContext db;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            db = new SampleDbContext();
            lst = db.Datagrids.ToList();
            InitializeComponent();
            additems();
        }


        public void additems()
        {
            data = new ObservableCollection<Datagrid>(lst);
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Updated");
            this.db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <ListView Name="lstCode" ItemsSource="{Binding data}" >


            <ListView.View>

                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Location" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="IsActive" Width="70">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Name="chk" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Name="btn" Height="23" Margin="0,0,201,85" Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="1.333,3.85" Click="btn_Click" />

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Is DataContext of Xaml set?

Comment: yea..Its set in the MainWindow additems method.

Comment: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and specify what to do when the value of IsChecked changes. [Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In this case, the collection is updating, but it's not communicating the changes to the database.

Comment: I bet that .ToList(); is making a copy so you no longer have a full connection back.

Answer (score 0):

Binding works through the INotifyPropertyChanged interface being implemented by your class. You notify whenever a property changes.

Looking at your code, the bigger issue is that it isn't in a proper MVVM format. To learn and probably solve your issue you should try the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) approach to coding in WPF.

An example link that explains it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained